# Looking to change certain button text to what is is the table

Tags: jquery

i am looking to change a buttons text to the table text inside a cell of a table.

The table is been populated by a database.

The code is meant to read the value from the 'status' field in the table and change the 'active' button to the same text.

But: its changing all buttons to the same text instead of just one.

The PHP

```
 echo "<tr class='id'>";
        echo "<td>$row->consult_id</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->consultant_name</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->job_title</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->client</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->pay</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->bill</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->cost</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->margin</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->startdate</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->enddate</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->recruited</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->account_manager</td>";
        echo "<td class='status'>$row->active</td>";
        echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-block active'>Active</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

The HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Consultant Id</td>
                <td>Consultant Name</td>
                <td>Job Title</td>
                <td>Client</td>
                <td>Pay</td>
                <td>Bill</td>
                <td>Cost</td>
                <td>Margin %</td>
                <td>Start Date</td>
                <td>End Date</td>
                <td>Recruited By</td>
                <td>Account Manager</td>
                <td>Activate State</td>
                <td>Change Activate State</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php echo readDatabase(); ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The Jquery

```
$('.status').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == "Inactive") {
       $('.active').text('Inactive');
       $('.active').removeClass('btn-success');
       $('.active').addClass('btn-danger');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code

```
$('.status').each(function() {
      var active_element = $(this).next('td').find('button.active');
        if ($(this).text() == "Inactive") { // I don't know you need $(this).text()  or the button text  active_element.text()
            active_element.text('Inactive');
            active_element.removeClass('btn-success');
            active_element.addClass('btn-danger');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of target all elements with `$('.active')` you will need to refer to the relative `button` using `this`.

Also you can reduce your code a little, try this:

```
$('.status:contains('Inactive')').each(function() {
    $(this).next().find('button').html('Inactive').toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger')
});
```